# Firebase phone authentication stops working no SMS

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We have developed app ios and android and it was working fine until now. We use firebase phone auth for validation but now we dont get the code by SMS.
We get back all the time "TOO MANY ATTEMPS, PLESE TRY LATER"

I appreciate your help.
Thanks.
Mikel.

We reactivate the firebase validation but nothing.
Any suggestions  ?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase phone number authentication not longer free, so you can use up to 10 sms daily for free and the rest is paid as the country sms price.